# How to sort based on several columns?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I got this dataframe composed of different columns (name, no_entrees_gratuites ie free visitors, year and region).

```
 $ name                : chr [1:13233] "Musée de la Folie Marco" "Musée de la Poterie" "Musée Alsacien" "Musée Historique" ...
 $ no_entrees_gratuites: num [1:13233] 2339 538 1329 3305 723 ...
 $ year                : num [1:13233] 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
 $ region              : chr [1:13233] "Grand Est" "Grand Est" "Grand Est" "Grand Est" ...
```

```
name               no_entrees_gratuites  year  region 
Musée du Louvre                4117897   2008  Ile-de-France
Musée Fabre                    131553    2008  Occitanie
Château de Versailles          1696929   2008  Ile-de-France
Musée d'Art et d'Histoire      602183    2008  Occitanie
Musée d'Orsay                  1327622   2008  Ile-de-France
Muséum d'Histoire Naturelle    150530    2008  Occitanie
```

I'd like to sort it and have the name of the top 3 most visited museums per year and region.

Something like that :

```
name               no_entrees_gratuites  year  region 
Musée du Louvre                4117897   2008  Ile-de-France
Château de Versailles          1696929   2008  Ile-de-France
Musée d'Orsay                  1327622   2008  Ile-de-France
Musée d'Art et d'Histoire      602183    2008  Occitanie
Muséum d'Histoire Naturelle    150530    2008  Occitanie
Musée Fabre                    131553    2008  Occitanie
```

I tried the arrange functions from the dplyr package but it is too broad for what I want.

```
musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year <- musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year %>% arrange(desc( no_entrees_gratuites))
```

I also tried the order function but it is too broad too.

```
musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year[with(musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year,order(musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year$no_entrees_gratuites, musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year$name)),]
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, please provide an example of your data set using the output of `dput(mydataframe)`.

Comment: @Phil The dput is really big and cover only a fraction of the dataframe (more than 13,000 entries). I've added a tibble to see the datatype of each column. Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "too broad"? The code you show should work to sort your data frame by the `no_entrees_gratuites` column in 2 different ways,  with `arrange` and with `order`. How does the result you get differ from the result you want?

Comment: *"per year and region"* perhaps this is a clue? Do you want to sort not only by `no_entrees_gratuites` but also by year and region? `... %>% arrange(year, region, no_entrees_gratuites)`? Or *"top 3 most visited museums"* do you also want to subset the data? Please be more clear about what you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas To respond to your first message :  The arrange and order code worked fine but It showed the most viewed museum by no_entrees_gratuites indeferently of years and region. As I am new to R, I supposed it is what the code was supposed to do.

Comment: @GregorThomas To respond to your second message : I want to be able to obtain the top 3 most visited museum by region and years according to no_entrees_gratuites which is the number of free visitors in a subset.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to you want to sort the data by year, region, and `no_entrees_gratuites`, and you also want to subset the data to show the top 3 `no_entrees_gratuites` by year and region. This should work for that:

```
musees_entrees_gratuites_per_region_year %>%
  arrange(region, year, desc(no_entrees_gratuites)) %>%
  group_by(region, year) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  ungroup()
```